# VC10 ATL Control Tutorial crashes in VB6

Tags: com, vb6, atl, vc10

It's been a long time since I dealt with VC ATL COM controls.  I am having issues upgrading a VC6 ATL control to VC10 when used in VB6.  In a step of troubleshooting I am now trying to follow the Microsoft tutorial[1] to create a VC10 ATL control and then place the control on a form in Visual Basic 6.  When the control is placed on the VB6 form in the VB6 IDE I get an error:

System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259).  Unspecified error

I test the control in the VC6 tool ActiveX Control Test Container and the control displays the green triangle and the properties can be invoked.

How do I get an ATL control to work in VB6?

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/599w5e7x.aspx

Comment: Ugh, 5 major releases later.  E_FAIL is useless, use the debugger.